# How to build a fully transition website?

Tags: web

Here the website I found on Google:
http://ui8.net/

This site is very creative, whole site is transition, between pages, it's clever to load page.

Do you know what is build on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site is build on angular js with specified router.
The answer comes from Codrops. Thanks for your answer.